# How to prevent the symbol "&" from being replaced by "&amp;"

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

I am looking to prevent the symbol "&" from being replaced by "`&amp;`" within my URL, specifically within JavaScript.

Just to expand on this requirement, I am getting my url from an oracle database table, which I then use within Oracle Application Express, to set the src attribute of an iframe to this url.

FYI, the url stored in the Oracle table is actually stored correctly, i.e.

```
http://example.com/xml/getInfo?s=pvalue1&f=mydir/Summary.xml
```

What appears in my use when trying to pass over into iframe src using JavaScript is:

```
http://example.com/xml/getInfo?s=pvalue1&amp;f=mydir/Summary.xml
```

which basically returns a page cannot be found

Comment: What does your URL come from?

Comment: um.. do you mean prevent &amp; from being replaced by & when it's sent through?

Comment: Can you provide some of the surrounding code to illustrate the problem? It's probably the case that your server-side code is "escaping" the ampersand, which would generally not be what you'd want for Javascript. However, we don't know what your server-side language is, so it's hard to say how to fix it.

Comment: You get a URL from somewhere using some method (and possibly you put the URL somewhere (which could be the same somewhere or somewhere else) using some other method) but you don't tell us where the somewheres are or what the methods are. It isn't possible to answer this without making some huge assumptions.

Comment: when encoding & into url in html you should always use `&amp;` instead of `&`, e.g. `<img src="http://site.cz/?a=0&b=1" />` should be indeed written as `site.cz/?a=0&amp;b=1` (right?), so someone automatically does that conversion (who? where?... we can't know); I think %26 can be used if you want to "pass" a literal `&`, e..g `site.cz/?a=0%26b=1` "assigns" to a `0&b=1`

Comment: @ShinTakeZou: the **browser** does that first conversion when it reads the HTML; the `&` *should* be encoded everywhere in XHTML (except in `CDATA` sections, of course). %26 will be translated to `&` by the **server**.

Comment: Hi all, I am updated my original post

Comment: How are you getting the URL into the iframe source - are you selecting it into a page item first for example?

Comment: Hi @Tony Andrews, yes I am. I am using a Before Header PL/SQL process and storing into a hidden page item.

Comment: @MvanGeest I know wwww of unescaping, "that conversion" refers to the OPer prblm (who changes his incoming & into correct escaped &amp;? I don't think js does that automatically, or does it?). "Right" is since Idk if all html specs require it (you confirm xhtml, I think html4 too, too lazy to check). Then, in the initial post wasn't clear if OPer wanted & (the special char that should be written &amp; in url too) or & (this exact char, which can be then wrtten %26); "I think %26..." is because of hypothetical matching of OPer requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you are doing something like this:

1) Selecting the URL text from the database into an Apex page item.

2) In Javascript, getting the URL text from the page item and using it to set the iframe source.

When you select the value in step 1, Apex will automatically replace the "&" by "&" so that the page HTML is valid - it will be something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="P1_URL" 
 value="http://mydomain.com/xml/getInfo?s=pvalue1&amp;f=mydir/Summary.xml" />
```

You will therefore have to reverse the transformation in your Javascript code - something like:

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').src = $v('P1_URL').replace('&amp;','&');
```

Comment: Hi Tony, just wondering if the .replace() call is a Apex V3.2 as I am using Apex v3.0.1 b/c I am getting a javascript error - Object exprected.

Comment: No, the replace() call is just Javascript.  More likely the problem is coming from the document.getElementById() or $v() functions, as these take a string Id and resolve it to an object.

Comment: ... so in my example there must be an iframe with id="myIframe" and a *rendered* Apex page item called P1_URL on the page.

Comment: Hi Tony, problem solved, thanks for your help. Basically instead of $v('P1_URL'), I just used '&P1_URL.'. All good now, thanks for your help. Thanks to all others also for your comments.

Comment: when pattern is a string, like this: `$v('P1_URL').replace('&amp;','&');`dose not worked for me, i used a RegExp for pattern: `$v('P1_URL').replace(/\&amp;/gi,'&');` and worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it caused me a lot of grief using PHP and JS.

This was how I solved the problem, using `substring(0,1)`.

```
function callAJAX()
    {      
        var var_Date = document.getElementById('DateAJAX').value;    
        var l2 = '&type=' + <?php echo $type; ?>; 
        var l2=l2.substring(0,1) + '<?php echo "type="  . $type; ?>';  // stupid js fix 
        jsfunction('ajaxdiv', 'phpfilename.php?date=' +var_Date + l2,'<? echo $num; ?>'); 
    }
```

The URL will result in something like:

```
phpfilename.php?date=2012-10-31&type=2
```

Yes, it's a long example, but I'm sure you can extract all the extra junk to be a minimalist example. :)